# working on a real time application using django

Tags: django, real-time, twisted, tornado

I have been researching this for a day or two. I am working on a real time application (a chat and a video chat). I am using django/apache combination which I understand is not suitable for this (at least the apache part).

In this regard I found several links from within stackoverflow such as http://www.skitoy.com/p/django-tornado-chat/305 and some comparisons such as the one at http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python

My question is. Can someone who has worked on django real time application let me know what framework I should use. It seems that I can use either django on tornado or use django with twisted framework. I am new to real time application and just need pointers so I can save some time.

Comment: I recommend you watch this video: http://2011.djangocon.eu/talks/43/

Comment: Another option may be to use a [hosted realtime solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#hosted-services). Is this an option for you?

Comment: ArgsKwargs, I am watching this as we speak.

Comment: leggetter, would check it out and let you know..

Comment: @ArgsKwargs, That definitely is a great video - Thanx for pointing it out!

Comment: There are many examples of this online - hotdot has a fairly complex example - https://github.com/clemesha/hotdot/ - or you can go with something simpler - http://ferretfarmer.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Some more tips here from people who've done similar:
http://eflorenzano.com/blog/post/technology-behind-convore/

### Update 2023-05-04

This Q and A are now 12 years old.  The article linked above is dead (as is Convore itself AFAICT), but can be found at: https://web.archive.org/web/20120819142511/http://eflorenzano.com/blog/2011/02/16/technology-behind-convore

I should have posted excerpts from it in my original answer.

> ...the first question developers tend to ask when they find Convore is "what technology powers this site?

Well, 12 years later the first question I am asking is "What is/was Convore?"

It seems to have been a "Hosted IRC" platform, i.e. something like Slack or Discord: https://www.ycombinator.com/companies/convore

> Convore is an online platform that enables its users to communicate with groups in real time. Its users have the ability to join an existing group or create groups of their own.
> Convore allows its users to post topics and have conversations with friends about those topics. The platform also provides its users with both public and private groups.

Ok, back to the original blog post:

> All of our application code is powered by Python. Our front-end html page generation is done by Django, which we use in a surprisingly traditional way given the real-time nature of Convore as a product.

> All of the important data is canonically stored in PostgreSQL, including messages, topics, groups, unread counts, and user profiles. Search functionality is provided by Solr, which is interfaced into our application by way of the handy Haystack Django application

> When a new message comes into the system ... a task is sent to Celery (by way of Redis) notifying it that this new message has been received ... then it publishes to a Redis pub/sub for the group that the message was posted to.

> Our live updates endpoint is actually a very simple and lightweight pure-WSGI Python application, hosted using Eventlet. It spawns off a coroutine for each request, and in that coroutine, it looks up all the groups that a user is a member of, and then opens a connection to Redis subscribing to all of those channels. Each of these Eventlet-hosted Python applications has the ability to host hundreds-to-thousands of open connections, and we run several instances on each of our front-end machines. It has a few more responsibilities, like marking a topic as read before it returns a response, but the most important thing is to be a bridge between the user and Redis pub/sub.

This basic architecture is still relevant today.

For Solr we might look to ElasticSearch. Rather than Eventlet (see also Gevent) we'd probably use Python 3 async features.

Additionally, Django itself now has support for real-time features via "Channels":

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

> Channels is a project that takes Django and extends its abilities beyond HTTP - to handle WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more. It’s built on a Python specification called ASGI.

Comment: This is now a 404.

Comment: @Glyph updated with contemporary context